# Inspecting WP_Rest_Request

Tags: rest-api

I'm implementing a callback for a GET [Wp Rest request](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/requests/), which receives a `WP_Rest_Request` object.

```
function create_on_demand_post( \WP_REST_Request $request ) {
    $params = $request->get_json_params();
    // etc...
}
```

There are [class methods](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_rest_request/#methods) which retrieve the request data, but I'm wondering if there's a way to access the data in this ArrayAccess implementation as I would with an array or object:

```
WP_REST_Request
    method:"POST"
    params:array(6)
    headers:array(8)
    body:"{"title": "From Python", "status": "publish", "content": "This is a post created using rest API", etc...}"
    route:"/my-plugin/v1/posts"
    attributes:array(7)
    parsed_json:true
    parsed_body:false
```

I have tried `$request->body`, which doesn't evaluate and `$request['body']`, as well as `$request['body'][0]`, both of which return `null`.

Are you only able to access the attributes using the provided methods?

Comment: Those properties are *protected*, so unless you extend the class, you should just use the public *method* to get the property value, e.g. use `$request->get_body()` for the `body` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted above in Sally CJ's comment, and as seen in the [Wp Codebase](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_rest_request/#source), those are *protected* properties, so they are meant to be accessed only through the multiple `get` and `set` methods that the class exposes:

```php
/**
  * Sets the header on request.
  *
  * @since 4.4.0
  *
  * @param string $key   Header name.
  * @param string $value Header value, or list of values.
  */
public function set_header( $key, $value ) {
    $key   = $this->canonicalize_header_name( $key );
    $value = (array) $value;

    $this->headers[ $key ] = $value;
}

// etc...
```

If you needed to access them directly, you would extend the class:

```php
class MY_WP_REST_Request extends WP_REST_Request {

    public $params;
    // etc...
}
```

Though in my case, using the access methods provided is proving to be fine.